# How do apps take you to another view when you click a button?

Tags: ios, button, view

For example, how do you code the play game button? Do you use different view controllers? Or is there another way to do if in. One storyboard or script? Someone please help me.

Comment: And how do apps do it which aren't "using Xcode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to have one ViewController per screen in your app. With Storyboards, you can "segue" (go from one view controller to another). A quick google search finds: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: Is this what apps like angry birds uses to switch between views? Does anyone know how "they" do it?

Comment: I dont know about Angry Birds (or games in general). But, a lot of apps use this approach.